# Fetching result from many to many relation tables based on condition

Tags: mysql, join, many-to-many

Working on creating a conditional filter query for the following tables. Created a fiddle with data [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mvyy1PJDYtPL4h7A7wivhH/4).

**Desired output** I want to write a single query which first fetches list of all products from translationproductdetials and later accepts filter parameters based on **produtypeid** and **cropid** (related to product by relation table with many to many relation).

| productid | trproductid | productimage | productname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Product/Img_1.png | other |
| 2 | 4 | Product/Img_2.jpeg | onion pesti panchaganga |

I get the product list for all using plain `select *` on transproductdetials. Also filter on producttypeid is achievable as its present in the productdetails table. The challenge is to filter on cropid as its many-to-many relation with products. So in my default query tried above and in fiddle I get all mappings of a product to all crops.

What I have tried is a plain query which fails due to the Many-to-Many relation between product and crop. A product can be associated with multiple products and vice versa. Can this be achieved using case when or some other approach is needed.

SQL tried:

```
select t.productid,tp.trproductid ,t.productimage,tp.productname,t.producttypeid, p.crop_id 
from productdetails t 
inner join  translationproductdetails tp on 
     t.productid = tp.productid 
left join productcrop p on tp.productid =p.product_id 
where tp.languageid=3 
ORDER by t.productid ;
```

Language

```
                   +--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
                   | Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
                   +--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
                   | languageid   | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
                   | inserttime   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
                   | insertedby   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
                   | insertedbyid | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
                   | updatetime   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
                   | languagename | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
                   | shortcode    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
                   +--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

cropdetails

```
              +-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
               | Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
               +-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
               | cropid            | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
               | cropnameeng       | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
               | cropimage         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
               | noofdays          | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
               | inserttime        | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
               | updatetime        | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
               | imagelastmodified | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
               +-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Productdetails:

```
     +----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
     | Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
     +----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
     | productid      | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
     | inserttime     | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
     | updatetime     | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                           |
     | productimage   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
     | productnameeng | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
     | producttypeid  | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
     +----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

translationproductdetails: Translation in multiple languages of above products from product table.

```
    +--------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
     | Field              | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
     +--------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
     | trproductid        | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
     | productdescription | text       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
     | productname        | text       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
     | languageid         | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
     | productid          | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
     | inserttime         | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
     | updatetime         | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |                                |
     +--------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

relation table productcrop: many to many relation table between crop and product

```
  +------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  | Field      | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
  +------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  | product_id | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
  | crop_id    | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
  +------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Looking forward for suggestions to achieve the result.

Comment: *Desired output* These rows in productdetails have no according rows in productcrop. Only product_id = 4 and 5 have according rows in crop. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9c4c833d6b7f86da8334d973f9562c52

Comment: @Akina My bad the fiddle has some limitation over no of characters and beyond that it does not allow. Hence I had to remove them. I will check if I can add it in your fiddle. Also I need to get product info based on language hence need it from translationproductdetails.

Comment: @Akina Updated the data here.Also I am using Mysql5.7.  Please check https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d7dcd036baa93be73c806bd04d0b2b9a

Comment: *Updated the data here* Please check the fiddle before posting. "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ```(`db_619382904`.`productcrop`, CONSTRAINT `FK9huenl01ixk5808fejblaoimf` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `productdetails` (`productid`))```". https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=be646cb3f53c6698dc8c34e36666d61c

Comment: @Akina Apologies new to the fiddle hence missed the error. Updated removing the constraint error https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=124fe49e3e9971a319819579e90bed63

Comment: Well, now last query gives 4 rows for 3 different `productid` values mentioned in `productcrop`. What must be performed (filtered, processed) with them additionally? What is desired output for this data? The output shown prevously is obviously incorrect (`productid` 1 and 2 does not present in last query output).

Comment: Yes as crop and product have a many to many relation 1 product can be associated with many crops and vice versa. Output I need is `productname` from `translationproductdetails`, `productid` and `productimage`  from productdetails filtered on `crop_id` from productcrop and `producttypeid` from `productdetails`. Hope I am clear.

Comment: *Output I need is productname from translationproductdetails, productid and productimage from productdetails* Add translationproductdetails to source list. (But there is no productid selected by the query from prev. iteration in translationproductdetails...) Type separate columns in output list instead of an asterisk simply. *filtered on crop_id from productcrop* It seems that joining condition have done this already. *and producttypeid from productdetails* Add according WHERE condition. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e6425bed748bc0b3b29a2dd0b28fb370

Comment: @Akina Yes the problem is for default condition or when the filter params are `null`.In case of `null` all results for cropid are populated against the productid due to many to many,I need a distinct or unique resultset in case of `null` params. The result is the same as mentioned in the question, off course we can have the filter params in the select clause, but otherwise list is the same. Sorry if I am unable to explain it properly in plain english

Comment: Look - in the last fiddle the pre-pre-last query selects 4 rows. Do you want to say that the amount of rows n this intermediate query must be greater, and `productid` values which are not present in `productcrop` must be returned nevertheless? Like in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e845de227b9e4f7e6181c41c754a4146

Comment: Hopefully now the result needed will be clear. I have updated the relation table productcrop and the result for your last query shows all cropid's related to a productid(For `productid` 8 three records viz `cropid` 8,9,10). Now what I want to achieve is -> Ex: when cropid and prodtypeid = null then show list of all products(unique list) and when they have values list filters based on values. Heres the updated fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c1fe4766131c970104496df947b9ac48

Comment: @Akina Did you have a look at the update? Is this possible using join alone or need a case when kind of a query?